# laravel -How to implement Heartland payment method in controller

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

In my website I’m using Stripe but for some reasons decided to change to Heartland Payment methods.
As I’m using laravel, so my knowledge is about controllers and models, I tried to understand how to do this with heartland but didn’t get it. For showing the input field it is working fine with me so now I want to make the payment by click submit button but I don’t know how to send these input information to controller to complete the payment.
Please I need good example showing process in the controller.
I tried to get the controller content from this link but didn't find clear one: https://developer.heartlandpaymentsystems.com/Ecommerce/Card
Thank you in advance

Here the code:

**route:**

```
   Route::get('/Payment/Charge', 'PaymentController@heartlandPost')->name('heartlandpost');
```

**Payment form and jquery code:**

```
   <form id="payment-form" action="/Payment/Charge" method="get">
  <div id="credit-card"></div>
  </form>

   <script src="https://api2.heartlandportico.com/SecureSubmit.v1/token/gp-1.0.1/globalpayments.js"> </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   GlobalPayments.configure({
  publicApiKey: "pkapi_cert_*****"
   });

    // Create Form
   const cardForm = GlobalPayments.creditCard.form("#credit-card");

 cardForm.on("token-success", (resp) => {
  // add payment token to form as a hidden input
const token = document.createElement("input");
token.type = "hidden";
token.name = "payment_token";
token.value = resp.paymentReference;

  // Submit data to the integration's backend for processing
  const form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
  form.appendChild(token);
 form.submit();
});

 cardForm.on("token-error", (resp) => {
// show error to the consumer
});
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function heartlandPost()

 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from reading the documentation, it *looks* like you need to do:

```
<?php
use GlobalPayments\Api\ServicesConfig;
use GlobalPayments\Api\ServicesContainer;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Address;
use GlobalPayments\Api\PaymentMethods\CreditCardData;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\ApiException;

public function heartlandPost()
{
    $config = new ServicesConfig();
    $config->secretApiKey = "skapi_cert_***";
    $config->developerId = "000000";
    $config->versionNumber = "0000";
    $config->serviceUrl = "https://cert.api2.heartlandportico.com";
    ServicesContainer::configure($config);

    $card = new CreditCardData();
    $card->token = $request->input('payment_token');
    $address = new Address();
    $address->postalCode = $request->input('postal_code');
    try {
        $response = $card->charge(10)
          ->withCurrency("USD")
          ->withAddress($address)
          ->execute();
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        // handle error
    }
    // return your response to the client
}
```

where you need to update the config to match your own keys and whatnot, and I''m not sure how you are passing the amount / postal code to your backend so make sure you do that as well.